# Get a scrollbar with { position: absolute; right: 0px; }

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, positioning

I need to align some elements in an iframe to the right and have it activate a horizontal scrollbar on the iframe when it gets squished.

The following code (in the iframe) works perfectly with a left positioning:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>lorem ipsum here</td>
                    <td>lorem ipsum here</td>
                    <td>lorem ipsum here</td>
                    <td>lorem ipsum here</td>
                    <td>lorem ipsum here</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
html{
    overflow:scroll;
}
table{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px;
}
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The exact same CSS with right positioning (right: 0px;) is broken, the horizontal scrollbar does not get activated.

EDIT: horizontal scrollbar

EDIT2: this HTML bit is in an iframe

EDIT3: Interestingly document.getElementById('tableID').scrollWidth gives accurate information about the scrollWidth the scrollBar should have but does not display. I might try an ugly ugly fix to my problem (ie create an artifical scroll bar, fml)

Comment: Yes it does. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Hexxagonal I forgot to add that the html is in an iframe. In that case it does not work in both FF 5 and Chrome 15

Comment: Does this reproduces the behaviour you're experiencing? - http://jsfiddle.net/ULnWF/1/

Comment: @MartijnB I actually don't know if {position: absolute; left: 0px;} is a valid/standard way to position it to the left (maybe the scrollbar in the "left" case is the browser falling back to a classic display)

Comment: @BenoitParis Sorry I don't have a answer for you right now. Have to go now, I will look tonight and post if I have a solution.

Comment: @BenoitParis I cannot come up with a proper solution. Unless you're happy to use the most ugliest hack you've haver seen, which I would btw NOT recommend you can use dir=rtl on the html tag - http://jsfiddle.net/ULnWF/6/ . While it works for the simple example it maynot for your real life page, because it could break your css layouts. Sorry for not helping you the proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get scrollbars, the table must appear in the flow; if you change its `position` to `absolute`, it's taken out of the flow, so without JavaScript to calculate figures (don't do that *ever*!) you can't do it.

It looks to me like what you want is just to remove the margin on the page. If this is correct, just put in your styles `body { padding: 0; }` (and remove the `position` and `left` from `table`).

Also, if you're just wanting it to scroll, you don't need to put it in an iframe (using iframes gratuitously is undesirable). `overflow: scroll` on the container is sufficient.

If you could post a more complete demonstration of what you're trying to achieve, more precise advice can be given.

Comment: I must use an iframe because the domains are different. Fortunately, I control both domains (but merging them is not possible). What I want to achieve is having the horizontal scrollBar activated in the bottom right zone of this page: http://jsfiddle.net/ULnWF/1/

Comment: @BenoitParis: so you want the iframe to be the minimum size which will entirely contain its content, as though it were a span or such? That you can't do in any way that I'm aware of (you can't even get the inside of it to report its size to the outside to manually change its dimensions in JavaScript because they're on different domains). If you could fetch it in an AJAXy way (you'll run into cross-site request problems though) and include it inline, that's the only way it can be done.

Comment: You read my intent correctly, I want to use the scrollbar width to adapt the iframe size. Actually I'm doing it through a browser extension, so passing things is a bit easier. It works now :D